# CanI upload many files in different folder using multer and a single html form?

Tags: node.js, file-upload, multer

I'm trying to develop a module that should upload files from a single html form.
Imagine a form that contains two files:
1) the avatar of the user;
2) the curriculum vitae the same user.
I would upload the first file in /avatar and the second in /cv.

I can use to do that three method:

```
.array('input file name');
.fields([{ name: 'avatar'},
```

{ name: 'curriculum'}]);
    . any()

The first accepts many files but its must have the same fields name;
The second accepts many files and its can have the names passed (and I think it should be right road for me);
the third accepts all files all names I set on html form.
Well, its work well but the problem is that I don't know how set different folders for each file!

The last trial was:

```
app.route('/upload').post(.upload(fileObj1).array('avatar'),upload(fileObj2).array('curriculum'),function (request, response, next) {
```

but it returns:

> Error: Unexpected field
>
> The problem isn't in other parts of code because if I launch this
>   code:
>   app.route('/upload').post(.upload(fileObj1).array('avatar'),function
>   (request, response, next) {

passing a single file it works correctly!
Someone can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved myself!
This is my not perfect solution (it works well for destination, filename and filetypes but not for maxsize and files) however, I want share my code:

in app.js I create an object like this:

var obj={
destination: {input-name1:'./uploads', input-name:'./uplds'},
filename: { input-name1:'file1', input-name2:'file2'},
FieldNameSize:undefined,
fieldSize:undefined,
fields:undefined,
fileSize:{input-name1:2*1024*1024, input-name2:10*1024*1024},
files:{input-name1:3,input-name2:1},
parts:undefined,
filetypes:{input-name1:"jpeg,jpg"}
};

and in rules_upload.js:

var path = require('path');
var multer  = require('multer');
var defaultMaxSize=3*1024*1024;
var defaultFiles=1;

exports.upload = function (obj, next) {
var upld = {};
var storage={};
var limits = {};
for (key in obj)
{
switch (key) {
case 'destination':
            storage.destination= function (request, file, cb) {
            cb(null,obj.destination[file.fieldname]);
            };
            break; 
case 'filename':
storage.filename=function (request, file, cb) {
    if(obj.filename[file.fieldname]!=undefined)
    {
                nome=obj.filename[file.fieldname];
                if(nome==undefined)
                    nome=file.originalname.substring(0, file.originalname.lastIndexOf("."));

```
                nome+=file.originalname.substring(file.originalname.lastIndexOf('.'),file.originalname.length);
```

}
else nome=file.originalname.split('/').pop().trim();

```
cb(null, nome);
        };
        break;
```

case 'FieldNameSize':
limits.fieldNameSize = function (request, file, cb) {
    if(obj.fieldNameSize[file.fieldname]!=undefined)
cb(null,obj.fieldNameSize[file.fieldname]);
else return cb(null, true);
};
break; 
case 'fieldSize':
limits.fieldSize= function (request, file, cb) {
    if(obj.fieldSize[file.fieldname]!=undefined)
cb(null,obj.fieldSize[file.fieldname]);
else return cb(null, true);
};
break; 
case 'fields':
limits.fields = function (request, file, cb) {
    if(obj.fields[file.fieldname]!=undefined)
cb(null,obj.fields[file.fieldname]);
else return cb(null, true);
};
break; 
case 'fileSize':
limits.fileSize = function (request, file, cb) {
    if(obj.fileSize[file.fieldname]!=undefined)
cb(null,obj.fileSize[file.fieldname]);
else return cb(null, true);
};
break; 
case 'files':
limits.files = function (request, file, cb) {
    if(obj.files[file.fieldname]!=undefined)
cb(null,obj.files[file.fieldname]);
else return cb(null, true);
};
break; 
case 'parts':
limits.parts = function (request, file, cb) {
    if(obj.parts[file.fieldname]!=undefined)
cb(null,obj.parts[file.fieldname]);
else return cb(null, true);
};
break; 
case 'filetypes':
        upld.fileFilter= function (req, file, cb) {
            if(obj.filetypes[file.fieldname]!=undefined){
            var f=obj.filetypes[file.fieldname];
            f=f.replace(",","|");
            var re= new RegExp(f);
            var mimetype = re.test(file.mimetype);
            var extname = re.test(path.extname(file.originalname).toLowerCase());
            if (mimetype && extname ) {return cb(null, true); }
            cb("Sono Accettate solo le seguenti estensioni: " + obj.filetypes[file.fieldname]);
            }
else return cb(null, true);
        };
        break; 
}
}
        if(storage.filename==undefined)
            storage.filename= function (request, file, cb) {
nome=file.originalname.split('/').pop().trim();
                cb(null,  Date.now()+"_"+nome);
            };
if(limits.fileSize==undefined)
    limits.fileSize=defaultMaxSize;
/*
var maxSize=l.maxSize;
            limitsfileSize= function (request, file, cb) {
if(file.size>(maxSize)) { cb(null,true); }
else { cb("Il file non può pesare più di"+maxSize+" MB" ); }
            };
            */
upld.storage= multer.diskStorage(storage);
upld.limits=limits;

return multer(upld).any();

};

Comment: @John Wick  are you speacking about indentation? Sorry but I'm totally blind and for me it is so hard do that at 100% that many times I don't check if it is correct. Could you tell me where is wrong? I will correct the code!