# How can I know which input send a certain opnedfiles in formidable?

Tags: node.js, file-upload, formidable

After this question:

[How set a function into limits parameters on multer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39787445/how-set-a-function-into-limits-parameters-on-multer)

that it doesn't receive an answer, I'm looking for an alternative and I'm seeing formidable.
I found different tutorial and now I have this code:

`exports.formidable= function (req, res, cb){
            var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
        form.multiples = true;
        form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files) {
            res.end(util.inspect({fields: fields, files: files}));
        });`

form.on('end', function(fields, files) {

for(var i = 0; i < this.openedFiles.length; i++) {
                /* Temporary location of our uploaded file */
                var temp_path = this.openedFiles[i].path;
                /* The file name of the uploaded file */
                var file_name =Date.now()+"-"+ this.openedFiles[i].name;
                /* Location where we want to copy the uploaded file */
                var new_location = './files/';

fs.move(temp_path, new_location + file_name, function (err) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.error(err);
                    } else {
                        console.log("success!")
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        return;

};

Now, if I iterate files in the first part of the code I receive some thing like [{input_file1:{file's attributes}},
{input_file2:{file's attributes}}]

and iterating openedFiles:
[{0: {file's attributes},
{1:file's attributes}}]

Now, can I be certain the both objects are in the same order? 
And, if the answer, as I suppose, is not, can I retrieve the input name from the second object?
If it's impossible, there are some workaround to do that?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I found a "dirty" solution but for now it works fine so I want share with you my code.
In rules_upload.js I add this code:

`var tmp='';
var x=0;`

form.on('fileBegin', function(name, file) {
    if(x>0)
    {
    this.openedFiles[(x-1)].fieldName=tmp;
}
    x++;
tmp=name;
});

form.on('end', function(fields, files) {
    this.openedFiles[(this.openedFiles.length-1)].fieldName=tmp;

So I adda new attribute called fieldName to retrieve this information!